# Why a simple html img tag is not appear?

Tags: html

I am making programming in html and using notepad. Everything seems to work correctly, however, when I came to add my image it doesn't appear, there is just an X I am using Microsoft Edge and the image is placed inside a folder called "My Website" and then placed in a folder called "images". Why is that below is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
        <meta http-equiv="firstwebsite" content="text/html; charset=uft-8"/>
    </head>  
    <body>
         <img src="flight.jpg" width="400px" height="300px"/>
    <div>
    <header>
          <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
    </header>
    </div>
    </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: `src="images/flight.jpg"` ?

Comment: I tried that just now, it added big space I think it worked. But Microsoft Edge is not supporting it. Do you recommend me to use another web browser

Comment: Not a browser compatibility issue. But anyway just give it a try

Comment: Of course Edge support it

Comment: Check your width/height on the image.. it may be adding more space than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the folder location of your image tag. Unless you need the photo a certain size, you don't need the width/height. It's also nice to include the `alt` attribute to your image tag if the image doesn't load correctly.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My Website</title>
            <meta http-equiv="firstwebsite" content="text/html; charset=uft-8"/>
        </head>  
        <body>
             <img src="images/flight.jpg" alt="image"/>
        <div>
        <header>
              <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
        </header>
        </div>
        </body>   
    </html>
```